# How to prefill field of type EntityType from PHP

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In my form, I have a field of type `EntityClass`:

```
$builder
    ->add(
        'user',
        EntityType::class,
        [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'User',
            'placeholder' => 'Please choose',
            'choice_label' => 'email',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
        ]
    )
;
```

This field works fine - until I try to pre-fill it from my PHP code. Then it stays empty, and only shows "Please choose".

Pre-filling looks like this:

```
$user = $this->userRepository->find(...);
$form->get('user')->setData($user);
```

But it also does not work if I call `->setData($user->getId())`, or even `->setData($user->getEmail())`.

So how do I prefill a field of type `EntityType`?

Comment: When and where do you set data?

Comment: Moreover, is that "main form" (so where you are calling the builder) binded to an entity or not?

Comment: @DonCallisto The form is not bound to an entity, and it's filled by a service that is called in the controller when `$form->isSubmitted()` returns `false`. (can't bind it to an entity due to having a relation to an entity that uses inheritance).

Comment: Please modify your question with all infos needed here. (entities, controllers, form, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not prefill `Form`, you should prefill `Model`, if you need it.

```
$user = $this->userRepository->find(...);

$entity = new YourEntity();
$entity->setUser($user);

$form = $this->createForm(YourEntity::class, $entity);
```

And it's not about `EntityType`. It's about any Type in Symfony - there is no way to bind a default value for them. Data is binded on Model.

UPD from comment: It's not true, that Form could be used without Model. It could be used without Doctrine Entity or any other ORM (or not ORM) Entity. But they still operate with data, i.o. with model.

**\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface** has definition

```
public function create($type = 'form', $data = null, array $options = array());
```

So some kind of `$data` is always present when you're using Form Component.

Comment: The forms in symfony are entirely separate from the entity thing - you can use them without having an entity at all. That's what the docs say. And for reasons (inheritance in related entity) I can't bind the model to the form.

Comment: That's not true. Forms could operate not necessary with Doctrine Entity (or any other ORM Entity), but they still operate with some Model. If you see a FormFactoryInterface, it's clear `public function create($type = 'form', $data = null, array $options = array());` - $data is model. What kind of model - it's up to you.

Comment: Ok, you're right - the data model may be a simple associative array. I've switched to just providing that associative array when creating the form, and now it works. Thanks!